# SQL Server Error: Cannot write property IsFileStream

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy usando por primera vez el SQL Server 2008 en una maquina de 32 bits y al momento de crear un nuevo proyecto me sale este error: Cannot write property IsFileStream. This property is not available on SQL Server 7.0 (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo).
Les agradeceria cualquier ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Yanina, quizas estos enlaces te puedan servir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762762/cannot-create-new-database-in-sql-server-2008 , https://www.techyv.com/questions/microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-cannot-write-properly-isfilestream/

Comment: a) en SQL Server no se crean _proyectos_. ¿Segura que es SQL Server? Si es así, ¿Qué es lo que estás creando?. b) ¿Alguna razón particular para usar SQL Server 2008 ahora en el 2020? Podrías utilizar SQL Server 2019, que es realmente superior al 2008 (que ya no tiene soporte por parte de Microsoft desde hace más de un año).

Comment: Parece que el problema no es que esté usando SQL Server 2008, sino ques se está conectando a SQL Server 7.0. Eso es previo al 2000 y debería de estar completamente en desuso.